# Can I dualboot UBUNTU with Windows 8.1 on my pc?

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, windows-8, 64-bit, intel

My PC specs:

NVIDIA GeForce GT610

Intel Core i3-4170 3.7GHz

64-bit 8GB RAM

Windows 8.1 Enterprise

I was planning to install 14.04 but I need to know if I can run it on my pc.

Comment: Yes, you can. This is better than my 2008 gaming rig that runs Ubuntu perfectly fine.

Comment: Not a duplicate, the thread you mentioned isn't 99% like this one.

Comment: Your system is UEFI, so follow UEFI install instructions. And with nVidia you may need nomodeset. I have a GT620 and for the first time with 14.04 or 15.10 did not have to use nomodeset and install nVidia driver to have it work. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system